# Arithmetic statements independent of ZFC and standard model of arithmetic

Tags: logic, set-theory, arithmetic

I would like to understand what is meant by the standard model of arithmetic. It seems to me that this object depends on the set theory in which one is working.

To explain this point: consider a formula in the language of arithmetic which is independent of ZFC set theory, $\phi$. For instance a diophantine equation which has a root if and only if ZFC is inconsistent. Now $T_1=$ZFC$+\phi$ is consistent and so is $T_2=$ZFC$+\neg\phi$. And in the first set theory $T_1$, $\phi$ is true in $\mathbb N$ the natural numbers with set $\omega=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\},...\}$, while in the second $\neg\phi$ is true.

Doesn't this show that the sentences of arithmetic which are true in the standard model, that is the theory of arithmetic, depend on the set theory one works with?

And by the way I cannot see how it would be otherwise because what human mathematicians do is only write down proofs in formal systems. And by the Church thesis any system strong enough like PA is equivalent to any other, though of course some are more practical and better known to us, for historical reasons and other reasons.

Thank you for any insight.

EDIT: Could you point to textbooks or articles where the author mentions this issue, and that there are different arithmetics (the complete theories of $\mathbb N$) depending on the set theory, or the universe of sets, assumed in use?

EDIT 2023: I did not remember having asked this already (i thought about mathematics somewhat differently in 2018). I found my question through google, after reading wikipedia's page on [true arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_arithmetic). I commented on the topic in the [talk page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:True_arithmetic#Dependence_on_metatheory), and if anyone feels like providing feedback i would appreciate it.

Comment: The axiom of infinity only guarantees the existence of something that "looks like" $\omega$; moreover the two models you describe will not have the same $\omega$ (provided $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is consistent.)

Comment: Why are you looking for someone mentioning this? In what context? You want this mentioned as a footnote, or as a whole chapter?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#Nonstandard_models

Comment: @AsafKaragila I would like to know whether major expositors of the basics of logic are aware that there is an important problem of definition. They usually talk about a single theory of arithmetic, but this is misleading, as it depends on our theory of sets. This is serious in my view, there really is a hiding of an important phenomenon.

Comment: Imagine yourself as a freshman, imagine a class full of students, all in their first week of mathematics. On the very first lecture, the instructor comes up to the board and says "Nothing is absolute in mathematics, not even the things we prove here. Everything depends on hidden assumptions that people are not going to tell you. TRUST NO ONE.", how well do you think these young minds will take it? Not well. Independence phenomena are difficult to stomach. You react like this is some grand conspiracy, but it's really a pedagogical choice.

Comment: @NotMike It seems to me that the wikipedia entry you are pointing to is not mentioning the dependence of arithmetic on the set theory one is assuming.

Comment: @AsafKaragila This is an interesting question, situation. I personally would have understood much better someone telling me that arithmetic and set theories are formal systems chosen rather arbitrarily for historical or practical reasons. In fact this is the conclusion I came to when I was a student, but I never came back to this until now to clear it up. I think it is an important point and I am sad that nobody seems to agree. I think it contributes to a kind of lie on what mathematics is. We are animals and the foundations of mathematics do fit with that.

Comment: And one of my professors said that he understood linear algebra when in the very first lecture his professor said that a vector space is an ordered $4$-tuple, or something like that. *Most* people are not like that. True, we need to also consider the survivor bias here, and how many of those who become mathematicians are like that. But there is a reason why you start with analysis over $\Bbb R$ and not with generalized functional analysis over Banach spaces, or over valuation rings, or so on. And ultimately, *most* people care about what they *prove* by hand using "reasonable" assumptions.

Comment: @plm "When interpreted as a proof within a first-order set theory, such as ZFC, Dedekind's categoricity proof for PA shows that **each model of set theory has a unique model of the Peano axioms, up to isomorphism, that embeds as an initial segment of all other models of PA contained within** *that* **model of set theory**. In the standard model of set theory, this smallest model of PA is the standard model of PA; *however, in a nonstandard model of set theory, it may be a nonstandard model of PA.* This situation cannot be avoided with any first-order formalization of set theory."

Comment: @NotMike: What is "the standard model of set theory", though?

Comment: @AssfKaragila A rhetorical device used by platonists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. The choice of your mathematical universe will affect the objects inside the universe.

If you believe that inaccessible cardinals are inconsistent, but I believe that they are fine, then we fundamentally disagree on $\Bbb N$.

But the standard model is called *the* standard model, because inside a universe of set theory there is exactly one standard model. And I think that no foundational theory is considered foundational if it does not have some sort of uniqueness theorems for $\Bbb N$ (and $\Bbb R$, while we're at it).

So yes, we can disagree on our meta-theory which in turn means we might disagree on $\Bbb N$. But we also agree that it has to be the unique models of $\sf PA$ which is well-ordered. And then we can ask, what are the things that we can both definitely prove from $\sf PA$, and in this grey area, there is a lot of interesting mathematics, and arguably where most of our efforts are concentrated (for better or worse).

Comment: Well, thanks alot. But people often say that there is _one_ theory of arithmetic, and this is false if we are right here. There is one for each set theory (at least there are many arithmetics), each universe. For instance if you look at the book of Boolos-Jeffrey they really claim there is a single arithmetic, but they never mention that they assume the set theorertical universe in which they work is fixed. And I have seen this in all writings on logic. This is highly misleading I believe.

Comment: I don't disagree with that. Pedagogical considerations, however, make it easier to start with that idea and slowly unveil the fickle dependency our mathematics has on the choice of universe.

Comment: @plm - this is venturing into philosophy of mathematics rather than math itself.  Many who identify as platonists believe there is exactly one "real" mathematical universe, which determines a unique standard model.of ZFC as well as a unique standard model.of PA. The answer here takes a different philosophical view.  For more description of platonism - which has a very long pedigree - see the Stanford Encyclopedia article [Platonism in mathematics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/platonism-mathematics/)

Comment: @CarlMummert Thank you. To me platonism is driven by emotion and misplaced. We are animals as far as any observation can indicate, physical objects, and we act to fit reality and satisfy ourselves. ZFC and its standard model(s) and those of PA suit our customs. Philosophers are just unable to accept that reality and are allowed by society to wax freely on their simple feelings. What is true is observation of our complicated psychology and physics, that is all. Thank you very much, as an expert's your view is essential.